# How can I set a TTL on a Kubernetes event?

Tags: kubernetes

I've a new service that emits so many events that etcd runs out of space. These are deleted up after 1h, but I'd like them to be deleted sooner. Is there any way to do set the TTL on each event?

Comment: You can use Kubernetes cronjob to delete these.

Answer (score 2):

There is a flag for [api-server](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/command-line-tools-reference/kube-apiserver/):

> --event-ttl duration     Default: 1h0m0s
>   Amount of time to retain events.